# Julia Atom bracket and quote autocomplete

Tags: julia, atom-editor

I could not find the option to enable bracket and quote autocomplete option in Julia, and the IDE I use is Atom. Anyone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to install a [lint](/questions/tagged/lint) for [julia-lang](/questions/tagged/julia-lang). Basically, it provides the auto completion features present in most fully-featured IDEs.

Simply open a terminal and type in the following command:

```
$ apm install linter linter-ui-default linter-julia
```